# Error in creating a volcano plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, bioinformatics

I am a complete newbie to MATLAB and the first task I have is to create a volcano plot. I have been using [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/mavolcanoplot.html) to understand about it and get started.

I tried to run it on dummy values -

```
a=[1 2 3]
b=[4.6 2.7 4.5]
c=[0.05 0.33 0.45]
```

And then I ran -

```
SigStructure = mavolcanoplot(a, b, c)
```

My understanding is that `a` represents the gene expression values for condition 1, `b` for condition 2, and `c` is the list of p-values for the 3 data points in `a` and `b`.

However running this code gives me the error -

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in mavolcanoplot (line 127)
appdata.effect = X(paramStruct.goodVals) - Y(paramStruct.goodVals);

Error in volc (line 4)
SigStructure = mavolcanoplot(a, b, c)
```

Can anyone explain where I am going wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps but the documentation says that c should be a column vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're encountering an issue because you are using row vectors.

Inside the `mavolcanoplot` function (you can see the file by typing `edit mavolcanoplot` in the command window) there is a local function for checking the inputs, called `check_inputdata`.

Your data passes all of the validation checks, and then encounters this section:

```
% Here, 'X' and 'Y' are the local names for your inputs 'a' and 'b'
% Below code is directly from mavolcanoplot.m:

% Handle the matrix input. Use its mean values per row
if size(X, 2) > 1
    X = mean(X,2);
end    
if size(Y, 2) > 1
    Y = mean(Y,2);
end
```

This reduces your inputs to their mean. Later in the main function (line 127) you encounter the error as described, where `paramStruct.goodVals` is a 3 element array, which is now trying to index a 1 element array and fails!

---

This is basically a lesson in debugging and reading the documentation, which states

> DataX, DataY: If a [...] matrix, **each row is a gene**, each column is a sample and **an average expression value is calculated for each gene**.

You should use one of these equivalent methods to **create column vector inputs**

```
a=[1 2 3].';       % Using transpose (.') to create a column vector from a row vector
b=[4.6; 2.7; 4.5]; % Creating a column vector using the semi-colon operator to end each row
c=[0.05
   0.33
   0.45];          % Using actual code layout to create a column vector
```