# What does the Matlab vector operation myVector.(':')(':') do?

Tags: matlab, vector

I came across the following expression in the function `mavolcanoplot.m`:

```
X = X.(':')(':');
```

I tried it with a simple example `X = [1 2 3]` but then I got

> Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object.

Since I don't know what the expression does, I don't know what `X` should look like to test it.

Can anyone tell me what the expression does?

Comment: Can you provide a link to said code?

Comment: It's in `mavolcanoplot.m` in the Bioinformatics Toolbox so I cannot really send you a link of the code but this is the question that led me to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46480021/error-in-creating-a-volcano-plot-in-matlab

Comment: The example you have tried it with is a matrix, the code you have taken this line from explicitly checks that `X` is of the data type `bioma.data.DataMatrix` before performing this operation.

Comment: I can't create that type of matrix to test it (I don't have the toolbox), so do you know what the expression does? And is this expression only applicable when you're dealing with that type of matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ug/representing-expression-data-values-in-datamatrix-objects.html#bsc5946-7),

> When using dot indexing with DataMatrix objects, you specify all rows or all columns using a colon within single quotation marks, `(':')`.

Take a look at this example:

```
import bioma.data.*
dmo = DataMatrix(rand(3,3), {'A', 'B', 'C'}, {'X','Y','Z'})

dmo = 

         X          Y          Z      
    A    0.69908    0.54722    0.25751
    B     0.8909    0.13862    0.84072
    C    0.95929    0.14929    0.25428

>> %to extract all rows and first two columns (X and Y)
>> %you can specify any of column scripts and column labels
>> %same goes for rows
>> dmo.(':')(1:2)   % or  dmo.(':')({'X','Y'})

ans =

    0.6991    0.5472
    0.8909    0.1386
    0.9593    0.1493

>> dmo.(':') %or dmo.(':')(':')  to extract all rows and columns

ans =

    0.6991    0.5472    0.2575
    0.8909    0.1386    0.8407
    0.9593    0.1493    0.2543
```

---

Furthermore, specifying a row/column label that doesn't exist gives `1` i.e.

```
>> dmo.('e')('X')

ans =

     1
```

and `end` cannot be used for indexing.

```
>> dmo.(end)('X')
Error: The end operator must be used within an array index
expression.
```

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that this is unusual MATLAB syntax, where for instance matrices would just use `(:)`. I believe this is a symptom of the DataMatrix object being able to have named rows and columns, which can be accessed by the corresponding string `X.('myRowName')`. This is more akin to a structure type, so the word "matrix" in "DataMatrix" is potentially misleading.

Comment: @Wolfie I never worked before with the DataMatrix object so thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Wolfie Although not very well known, `':'` can also be used instead of `:`  for numeric arrays, character arrays, or cell arrays. Try `x = magic(3); x(':'); y = num2cell(x), y(':')`